# Rspec: how can I check if a call to a method of another class is called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2

I can I check if FeedItem::populate_from_friend_to_user is called inside the user class?

```
    it "should auto populate feed after user.add_friend" do
      @user.add_friend(@friend1)
      @user.should_receive('FeedItem::populate_from_friend_to_user').with(@friend1, @user)
    end
```

With the above code I get:

```
undefined method `populate_from_friend_to_user' for :FeedItem:Symbol
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You should not know **where** the method is called, just **if** the method is called.. You just know if the method is call:

**Before RSpec 3**

```
 it "should auto populate feed after user.add_friend" do
    FeedItem.should_receive(:populate_from_friend_to_user).with(@friend1, @user)
    @user.add_friend(@friend1)
 end
```

**In RSpec 3** the syntax is

```
expect(Object).to receive(:method).with(params)
```

Comment: This is `Object.should receive(:method).with(params)` now

Comment: @ChrisNicola: my experience doesn't bear this out?

Comment: In RSpec 3, this is now `expect(Object).to receive(:method).with(params)`

Answer (score 11):

Remember that is works only in rspec2 . For rspec3 u call

`expect(@user).to receive(:your_method)`

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/message-expectations

Comment: what if `:your_method` is a class method?

Comment: Then you don't expect to run it on object i suppose?  I am not sure if i got your question ;]

Comment: If you want to test if a class method is called, do this. `expect(User).to receive(:your_method)`

Comment: You can also specify how many times you expect class to receive method, e.g.: `expect(User).to receive(:your_method).thrice`